# syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php

i have to trouble trying to debug this code and i know it´s something on line 26 and i have tried different methods to solve it like changing it to mysql and defining db

```
<?php
session_start();

include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
    include ('/ClassLogin.php');  
    $login = new Login();
    if
        ($login->isLoggedIn())
        header('location: indeks.html');
    else 
        $login->showErros ();
}
$Token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),TRUE));

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT id FROM $tbl WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
class db extends mysqli 
{


  function __construct($localhost, $username, $password, $pokemon7_users, $port=80){
   mysqli::__construct($localhost, $username, $password, $pokemon7_users, $port);
    } 
    $result = mysqli($db, $sql, $link);

if (!result)
{
    printf("Error: ", mysql_error($link));
}
else
{
    Echo "Congratulations you are now logged in";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the dollar :)

`!result` -> `!$result`

Also don't mix between `mysqli` and `mysql`. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should not use them anymore.

It would be better and more readable to define classes in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

This

> if (!result) {

must be

> if (!$result) {

Your missing the Dollar sign

Answer (score 0):

replace if (!result)  by if (!$result)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and you did not closed your class:

```
class db extends mysqli 
{
  function __construct($localhost, $username, $password, $pokemon7_users, $port=80)
  {
    mysqli::__construct($localhost, $username, $password, $pokemon7_users, $port);
  }
}
```

Also there are a typos:

```
if (!result) to if (!$result)
```

Also i can not find any data which you pass for database info for example $localhost